# I cannot import a specific .py file from the folder i have in google drive , it throws an error

Tags: python

```
# loading dataframes using dataset module 
import os
os.system("/content/drive/My Drive/Project/Emotion Speech Recognition/utils/dataset.py")

from utils import dataset
df, train_df, test_df = dataset.create_and_load_meta_csv_df(dataset_path, destination_path, randomize, split)
```

Comment: The error is - cannot import name 'dataset' from 'utils'

Comment: please upload the file structure and utils folder.

Comment: did you missed /path/to/utils/__init__.py?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to import the file where instead you are opening it in another python instance.

to import the file you should add its module directory to the python path then import it.

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/content/drive/My Drive/Project/Emotion Speech Recognition')
    
from utils import dataset
```

instead of

```py
os.system("/content/drive/My Drive/Project/Emotion Speech Recognition/utils/dataset.py")
```